# How to change user registration form fields for different type of user roles in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, roles

I have a two user roles named

1. employer
2. Job seeker

I need to display different registration form fields for each role.

for employer - registration fields are

company name
Address
Phone
zipcode
Contact Person

for job seeker - registration fields are

Firstname
Lastnanme
email address

I have used profile role module, user selectable role module. But I am not able to perform this process.

Please help me to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

I found my result here

http://drupal.org/node/170023#comment-3300274

It is useful.

Comment: The given detailed information is more useful. modules are content profile and autoassignrole